# NEAR Indexer Framework - Raw data instead of String for view types

Tags: blockchain, nearprotocol

It appears the NEAR Indexer framework do different transformations (i.e. [FunctionCall#args](https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/master/core/primitives/src/views.rs#L846)) for presenting the data to developer wrapping NEAR primitives types into `View` type.

It turns for example the `FunctionCall#args` field from a `Vec<u8>` to a `String` by doing a `base64` encoding of the value. For the `DeployContract`, it gives the `hash` of the data. And others like that.

Is it possible to access the raw data instead of the `view` and avoid those conversions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around it at the moment. Eventually, Indexer Framework should introduce its own structs and avoid coupling with the view structs.